# How to add column labels to graphs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I was wondering, if you can annotate every graph in this example automatically using the column headers as labels.

```py
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    
    d = {'a': [100, 125, 300, 520],..., 'z': [250, 270, 278, 248]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[25, 26, 26, 30])
```

```py
             a    ...     z
  25        100   ...    250
  26        125   ...    270
  26        300   ...    278
  30        520   ...    248
```

When I use this code, I only get the column headers as a legend. However, I want the labels to be directly beside/above my graphs.

```py
sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False, estimator=None)
```

Comment: You cannot do this automatically. You must use `annotate` or similar manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False, estimator=None, legend=False)

for label, pos in df.iloc[0].iteritems():
    ax.annotate(label, (df.index[0], pos*1.05), ha='left', va='bottom')
```

output:

[image: annotated graph]

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, dashes=False, estimator=None)

for c, l in zip(df.columns, ax.lines):
    y = l.get_ydata()
    ax.annotate(f'{c}', xy=(1.01,y[-1]), xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), 
                ha='left', va='center', color=l.get_color())
```

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703420/15239951